# code signature verification using Python and windows interoperability

Tags: python, code-signing

I want to verify a code signature using python. I read about tools provided by Microsoft for generating a code signature (Microsoft Authenticode for e.g) but how do i verify the same using Python ?  I have a code signing cert. My client has the root cert of the issuer in order to verify the chain for the public key. I want to ensure i verify is properly (timestamp etc) without having to write custom code. Is there a package which does that or do i need to implement it ?

Comment: I understand that this was migrated here, but IMO, it is off-topic for SO: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. ..."*  from the [help/on-topic]

Comment: @SiHa Where is the request to recommend tool? This is about doing very clear task. IMO not opinion-based.

Comment: @gonczor My feeling is that *"Is there a package which does that"* is a request for a software library. Others may not agree, which is their (and your) prerogative.

Comment: @SiHa " or do i need to implement it". And it's not the core of the problem. But I can see your point.